# How to forcefully redirect from http to https on AWS ec2 with Nginx

Tags: http, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, http-status-code-404

I am using AWS ec2 for Hosting my Web Application which is running on PHP.I have SSL for it but due to some of my old backlinks which are having http request. When this request gets called my server blocks http request with response of Error 400, So i want to forecefully redirect that http request to https.

I have tried adding `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to my Nginx Config File but it is not working

My Nginx Config File

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

What can i do so that the request from http get redirected to https....?

Comment: Does your nginx configuration have a server that listen en 443/HTTPS?

Comment: @Mtxz Yeah I have opened Port 443 from aws console panel but In Nginx configuration file It is not mentioned about 443

Comment: I think that you need a 443 configuration for your Nginx. Here, you redirect all requests to https. But if your Nginx does not have a 443 listening server, nothing can answer that. Of course, you'll need a valid SSL certificate.